# how to add a button with icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have a button in my app like

[image: this]

And below is the code for the same

```
Widget loginButtonChild = const Text(
  "Log in",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular",
  ),
);


FlatButton.icon(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
  color: Colors.red,
  label: loginButtonChild, 
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward ), 
  onPressed: () {
   //some function
  },
)
```

I am trying to create a button something like

[image: this]

Can anyone help in this or any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Label", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          SizedBox(width: 6),
          Icon(Icons.chevron_right, color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 10):

First off, [`FlatButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) and [`RaisedButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) are *deprecated*. Use `TextButton` and `ElevatedButton` instead.

If you want to add an icon to a text button, use `ElevatedButton.icon` or `TextButton.icon` constructor. It will add the icon to the left of the text.

However if you want to add the icon to the right of the text. swap the icon with text and vice versa. This works because both icon and text params are `Widget`

```dart
// icon before text
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 16),
  label: Text('Icon Button'),
  onPressed: () => {},
),
```

```dart
// icon after text
ElevatedButton.icon(
  icon: Text('Icon Button'),
  label: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 16),
  onPressed: () => {},
),
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/6e8c4dff9ebaabf2980ae05fee8ae109?null_safety=true)

Answer (score 1):

`FlatButton.icon` puts the icon on the left, what you can do is use `FlatButton` and in the child put a `Row` with the label + icon, like this:

```
FlatButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      loginButtonChild,
      const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
      Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
    ],
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    //some function
  },
)
```

If you want to have the button with elevation, just change `FlatButton` for `RaisedButton`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I increased size of button text going left, but I adjusted that by padding , Thanks!